# service starts before /dev/serial is set up, how to prevent?

Tags: linux

I have a service that starts at multi-user and does a bunch of stuff with some serial devices. One of the first things is does is search for the serial devices it cares about and opens them. Since serial devices come and go, the devices it opens is configurable, and at start it walks through /dev/serial/by-id, looking for things that match the configured patterns.

Sometimes, it doesn't find matches at boot. If I restart the server later it does find them.

I can do wonky things in the code like polling over /dev/serial until it has content, but that feels clumsy and raceish. I'd really like to defer starting the service until whatever is setting up /dev/serial/by-id is finished. How do I?

If they just aren't there at system boot, the service is expected to carry on without them. So I need to know when detection is finished; I can't just loop until they appear. Maybe they won't.

Comment: what's your init?  sysv, upstart, systemd ?

Comment: systemd is the init of choice

Comment: so you need to create your systemd unit to depend on the unit that fills in /dev/, but I don't know the details of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

No one seems to know how to do this, and I ended up coding a thread that just hangs around, periodically checking for /dev/serial/by-id and then harvesting what it finds there. It works, but it's annoying that I'd have to do this. Still interested in better ways if anyone knows of any.